# Windows 10: Disable file search in Start Menu search box

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

Is there a way to prevent Windows 10 to search in files in the Start Menu search box? (The thing you get after hitting Windows button and then typing).

Answer (score 1):

You can only exclude folders/disks from Windows Search, which will have effect
for all of Windows, not only for the Start Menu search.

This is how:

- From the Start Menu, run Indexing Options
- Click the *Modify* button
- In the Indexed Locations window, navigate to the folder(s) you want to exclude
- Uncheck the location(s)
- Click OK.

If you wish to totally disable Search, see the article
[Enable or Disable Search Indexing in Windows](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/93666-enable-disable-search-indexing-windows.html).

Answer (score 0):

As of Windows 10 version 1909, it is not possible to disable the file search functionality in the start menu, but it is possible to set it to exclude all your partitions from the search, making in fact equivalent to disabling it.

To do so, press the windows key and start typing *Exclude folders from being indexed*, then press the `+` button next to the *Add an excluded folder* and select all your partitions one by one.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To turn this off in later versions of Windows 10, just set File Explorer to show hidden files:

[image: Click on View tab, then click on checkbox for 'Hidden Files']

Then you can find this location in the *Indexing Options* → *Indexed Locations* to disable it at `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu`.